# Imposer une « chape de silence » ?

Tags: sens, usage, lexique, mots-composés, politique

> Internet censuré, militants arrêtés, presse muselée : le gouvernement
>   chinois impose **une chape de silence** à l'occasion des 30 ans mardi de
>   la répression sanglante des [manifestations de la place Tiananmen](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifestations_de_la_place_Tian%27anmen) à
>   Pékin. — article *Surveillance renforcée à Pékin pour les 30 ans de Tiananmen* ds. [Lapresse.com](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/asie-et-oceanie/201906/03/01-5228648-surveillance-renforcee-a-pekin-pour-les-30-ans-de-tiananmen.php)

Une [*chape*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chape) c'est entre autres une forme de manteau et on a la *chape de plomb* pour l'« ancien instrument de torture consistant dans un manteau de plomb » (TLFi) ou au figuré pour le « silence, le plus souvent imposé par une autorité sur un sujet » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chape_de_plomb)), entre autres. D'autre part on a aussi d'autres emplois de *chape* par métaphore ou au figuré comme *chape de glace, de neige; chape de silence* (TLFi). Par ailleurs on a d'autres termes avec des emplois possiblement reliés au figuré comme le [baîllon](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ba%C3%AEllon), l'« obstacle à la liberté d'expression » (TLFi), voire l'emprunt à l'anglais [*blackout*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/blackout#fr) pour le « silence médiatique sur un sujet » (Wiktionnaire) etc.

- En quoi la *chape de silence* diffère-t-elle de la *chape de plomb*
  au figuré et pourquoi l'une et pas l'autre dans le texte ; de quoi s'agit-il ?

  - Quelle est la différence de sens ou de connotation entre *imposer une
    chape de silence* et *imposer le silence* tout court ?
  - Quelle propriété de la *chape* interagirait avec le *silence* : est-ce
    l'étendue/la grandeur ou le poids oppressant etc. ; est-ce la liste précédant le deux-points qui motive l'emploi ?
- Connaît-on l'origine de l'emploi, est-il courant dans ce genre de contexte (la politique des états totalitaires) ou peut-on en identifier un exemple célèbre en littérature ?

Comment: C'est la première fois que je lis *chape de silence*. *chape de plomb* est usuel. Je soupçonne une erreur du rédacteur !

Comment: @Damien C'est possible, mais _chape de silence_ apparaît directement au TLF, qui donne cependant un exemple avec _chape d'oubli_.

Comment: Effectivement, mais je suis surpris. J'essaierai de vérifier dans mes bons vieux dictionnaires papier !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### La chape de silence: une expression inutile ?

On propose [en une autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/36801/13100) que la chape de plomb possédant, dans son arsenal d’effets directs, celui d’imposer le silence, l’expression figurée *chape de silence* serait inutile, inutilité que l’on justifie et renforce par l’affirmation qu’on rencontre surtout l’expression en journalisme (genre moindre, je suppose) et moins en littérature.

Je perçois la chose différemment. La chape de silence, pour un, ne tue pas directement. Elle pourrait possiblement mener à la mort par une succession d’effets (si par exemple il n’est pas permis de parler d’une famine, on pourra s’attendre à ce que bien peu d’aide extérieure vienne soulager les souffrances, et que des gens meurent d’inanition), mais le plus souvent, c’est tenter de briser la chape de silence qui pourrait s’avérer risqué pour la vie.

---

#### De la chape et la chape de plomb à la chape de silence

La chape, on l’a dit dans la question, est une sorte de manteau. Un manteau isole le corps de l’environnement.

La chape de plomb, instrument de torture au sens premier, fut nommée d’après la chape vêtement par analogie de forme, non par souci d’isolation. En son sens figuré, il s’agit d’un fardeau moral écrasant, difficile à porter, ruinant plus ou moins l’existence en débordant dans tous les aspects de l’existence de quelqu’un.

En une sorte de fertilisation croisée, la séparation physique offerte par le manteau et l’oppression de la torture peuvent facilement mener à la **chape de silence**. On abandonne l’aspect réconfortant, chaleureux, de la cloison offerte par le manteau, mais on laisse aussi de côté le poids physique et les intentions de mort de la chape de plomb. On insiste plutôt sur l’étanchéité du premier, et le caractère oppressif du second.

La chape et la chape de plomb contribuent tous deux à la signification de la chape de silence, mais partiellement dans un cas comme dans l’autre.

---

#### De la matérialité du silence

On pourra arguer que le silence est bien peu substantiel, qu’un son suffit à le briser, tout comme l’obscurité n’est qu’une absence de lumière que la moindre lueur anéantit.

Ça me semble néanmoins faire bien peu de cas du silence. Depuis déjà longtemps un proverbe le dit d’or. On parle aussi parfois d’un **silence lourd** ou **pesant**. Plus récemment, depuis le début du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, une autre image émerge : le [**silence assourdissant**](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&startRecord=0&maximumRecords=15&page=1&query=%28gallica%20adj%20%22silence%20assourdissant%22%29&filter=century%20all%20%2220%22). En voici [un exemple](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k96097096/f91.image.r=%22silence%20assourdissant%22?rk=21459;2) signé Léon Deubel, datant de 1913, auquel on ne saura reprocher d’émaner du journalisme :

> Main tendue à ceux qui s’élancent
> Hors de l’in-pace de la chair,
> Pour s’évader dans le **silence**
> **Assourdissant** des univers,
>         Poésie !

Par ailleurs, les parents savent bien qu’il faut savoir **entendre le silence** : c’est lorsque les enfants sont silencieux qu’ils manigancent des actions qu’ils savent ou supposent interdites par leurs parents. Gare à ceux qui savoureront le soudain silence comme un moment de répit dans le vacarme habituel du quotidien !

---

#### La chape de silence oppressante

On supposera un désir d’imposer le silence quand un événement présumé important n’est pas documenté, discuté, débattu, commenté, commémoré. Ce n’est pas une chape de plomb. Le climat est sans doute contraignant et oppressant, un gouvernement peut utiliser la torture, l’emprisonnement préventif et toutes sortes de moyens douteux pour l’imposer, mais ce n’est pas systématiquement requis. La **honte** d’une communauté pour les actes de certains de ses membres peuvent aussi créer une chape de silence auto-imposée. La simple **crainte** de perdre son emploi pourrait avoir les mêmes effets pour des employés de certaines compagnies.

Le silence en certaines circonstances surprend, et la *chape de silence* me semble une **hypothèse défendable** dans certains cas pour justifier ce silence inattendu.

---

Quelques exemples (non ! pas véritablement de la littérature !) :

> L’auteur en rend responsable, outre ses propres scrupules, une persécution dont il aurait été victime et qui aurait éteint l’oeuvre à peine née sous une **chape de silence.**
>     <sub>—Revue d’histoire littéraire de la France, [1968](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k57278324/f45.item.r=%22chape%20de%20silence%22)</sub>
>
> C’est elle qui a soulevé la **chape de silence** qui pesait si durement à tous. Car c’en est fini du silence auquel on prétendait nous réduire.
>     <sub>—L’Humanité : journal socialiste quotidien, [1915](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k254231q/f2.item.r=%22chape%20de%20silence%22)</sub>

Possiblement auto-imposée :

> Est-il nécessaire d’ajouter qu’aujourd’hui une **chape de silence** est tombée sur les noms de ceux qui, de près ou de loin, sont responsables de la destruction des allégories de la Justice et de la Force ? Peut-être cela prouve-t-il, de leur part, un certain remords accru par le lent revirement d’opinion qui s’exprime depuis quelques années en faveur des œuvres inutilement saccagées.
>     <sub>—Bulletin de la Société académique des Hautes-Pyrénées, [1999](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6535066j/f158.item.r=%22chape%20de%20silence%22)</sub>

---

#### La chape de silence simplement enveloppante

Parallèlement à la chape de silence imposée existe la chape de silence impromptue, un ange qui passe :

> Un moustachu impertinent - se souvenant peut-être d’un temps où l’on parlait de « ski de printemps » - pose une question stupide, qui fait tomber une **chape de silence** : « Au fait les gars, on est d’accord pour l’épreuve olympique de ski-alpinisme à Bercy. Mais vous voyez ça plutôt en hiver ou en été ? »
>     <sub>—Causses et Cévennes : revue du Club cévenol, 1985</sub>

Pas forcément négatif, d’ailleurs :

> Les rues sont désertes et la montagne étend sur la petite ville stupéfiée **une chape de silence.**
>     <sub>—La Montagne et Alpinisme : revue du Club alpin français et du Groupe de haute montagne, 1994</sub>
>
> L’heure des saluts sonnait aux paroisses. Heure aussi des sabots, petits sabots d’enfants, lourds sabots d’ouvriers, lents sabots traînés de vieilles femmes et qui se mettent à tricoter la **chape de silence** où tantôt s’endormira la ville...
>     <sub>—Femina : publication bi-mensuelle illustrée, [1910](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5495832q/f26.item.r=%22chape%20de%20silence%22)</sub>

Comment: On fait bien des trouvailles intéressantes sur Gallica !

Answer (score 2):

La *Chape de plomb* est, à l'origine, un instrument de torture du Moyen-Âge. De lourdes plaques écrasant la cage thoracique de la victime.

Ainsi, cette expression est utilisée pour désigner l'oppression, la servitude.

On l'utilise également pour désigner un fardeau moral.

Et... Le silence (imposé).

L'expression *Chape de Silence* est donc, à mon sens, un non sens.
On la rencontre d'ailleurs presque uniquement dans les articles de journaux, pas dans la littérature.

Elle ne fait son apparition que très tard, selon [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chape%20de%20silence%2Cchape%20de%20plomb&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchape%20de%20silence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchape%20de%20plomb%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cchape%20de%20silence%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cchape%20de%20plomb%3B%2Cc1)

Enfin, pour répondre a ta dernière question, je te laisse chercher ici :) :
[Google Books : Chape de plomb](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1674&bih=977&tbm=bks&ei=ACz6XJKRDtKWaYSimJAC&q=chape%20de%20plomb&oq=chape%20de%20plomb&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0.0.10580.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.w54p6TxOqJA)

Comment: «L'expression *Chape de Silence* est donc, à mon sens, un non sens.» Pardonnez-moi de ne pas avoir exactement suivi la logique aboutissant à ce *donc* utilisé ici pour une conclusion que je n’avais pas vue arriver.

Comment: L'expression "Chape de plomb" désignant déjà le silence imposé par une autorité, l'expression "Chape de silence" n'a pas lieu d'être, par essence. La logique de la locution sus-citée est-elle davantage à votre convenance ?

Comment: Ça me semble plus clair mieux explicité comme vous venez de le faire. Merci.

Comment: Mais je vous en prie. Au plaisir de vous revoir.

Answer (score 2):

Une [chape](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chape), c'est à l'origine **la tête** (Le latin *caput* ayant donné *cap*/*chief*/*chef*...) **d'un clou**. C'est la partie haute, aplatie qui le recouvre une fois planté.

Le mot ***chape*** est donc apparenté à toutes sortes de choses qui recouvrent, un chapeau, un chef, une cape, un chapiteau, un chapitre, etc.

On a revêtu des condamnés d'une cape/**chape de plomb** qui les étouffait, mais ce pouvait aussi être des ecclésiastiques qui revêtaient une cape plus classique, une **chape de velours**.

Le mot *chape* s'est ensuite spécialisé pour désigner une couche épaisse, s'éloignant de vêtement.

> Une **chape de ciment**
>   Une **chape de béton**

L'instrument de torture n'a subsisté qu'au sens figuré, pour recouvrir et étouffer d'une "couche de plomb" virtuelle ce qui se trouve dessous

> Une **chape de plomb**

La français étant une langue vivante, rien n'interdit d'étendre encore cette image pour désigner quelque chose qui recouvre d'une couche plus ou moins abstraite :

> Une **chape de fumée**
>   Une **chape de silence**
>   Une **chape d'oubli**
>   Une **chape d'invisibilité** (qu'Harry Potter ne renierait pas...)